# How to uniform results of request security based on timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How can I switch between using request.security() and request.security_lower_tf() in Pine Script based on the timeframe?

These functions return two different data types: the first returns a series of float, while the second returns an array of float.

How can I uniform them so that I can switch between them seamlessly?

For switching the function could be something like that:

```
if timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period) < timeframe.in_seconds(tf)
    result = request.security_lower_tf(stringaMomentum, timeframe, close - open)
else
    result = request.security(stringaMomentum, timeframe, close - open)
```

but what type should I declare result? The function returns several types.
And how can I calculate the indicators on it (e.g. `ta.sma(result, 50)`), if the type is changed (non-series)?

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example ? I don't get which timeframe is on your chart and how you choose the other timeframe. What event trigger the 'switch' in timeframe ?

Comment: I have to make a function that has input a timeframe I have to figure out if it is above or below the current one and use the correct function.
If higher I will use request.security otherwise request.security_lower_tf

Example: I opened the AAPL chart on a 1 day timeframe and I want to retrieve the data from the same 30 minute and 1 week chart.
In the first case (30 minutes) I will use the request.security_lower_tf function, while in the second (1 week) I will use request.security

Comment: ok : you open AAPL chart on a 1 day timeframe and you want to calculate the indicator ta.sma( result, 50) on the 30 minute timeframe. How do you want to see the result ? In this case you hace 1 bar (of 1 day) on your chart, and you have 48 value for this bar. Which value would you like to see on your chart ?

Comment: @G.Lebret I don't care to see the result on screen. I just have to do some calculations on it, so I don't want to draw the ema but only have the values of it (the last and the previous one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script providing an array with all the values of the lowest timeframe between the chart timeframe or the asked timeframe choosen by the user

```
//@version=5
indicator("TimeFrame Switcher")

AskedTimeframe = input.timeframe("D", "Timeframe used for calculation")

if timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period) < timeframe.in_seconds(AskedTimeframe)
    // Used to prevent error in the line resultLTF = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, AskedTimeframe, close - open)
    // if a greater timeframe is asked, we don't need resultLTF
    // but in request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, AskedTimeframe, close - open)
    // the AskedTimeframe must be equal or lower to the chart time frame
    AskedTimeframe := timeframe.period

resultLTF = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, AskedTimeframe, close - open)// Array
resultHTF = request.security(syminfo.tickerid ,AskedTimeframe,  close - open) // float

var result = array.new_float(0, na)
if timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period) > timeframe.in_seconds(AskedTimeframe)
    // We need to copy the array in resultLTF to result
    result := array.concat(result, resultLTF)
else
    // We need to create X times the resultHTF value in the array
    // How many bars of the actual timeframe are in one bar of the AskedTimeframe
    NbBars = int(timeframe.in_seconds(AskedTimeframe)/timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period))
    ArrayToAdd = array.new_float(NbBars, na)
    array.fill(ArrayToAdd, resultHTF)
    result := array.concat(result, ArrayToAdd)
// At this point, result is an array containing All the data from the lowest time frame, in chronological order
// The array is at his max size when the AskedTimeframe is equal or greater than the chart timeframe
if barstate.islast and false // set to thrue to see the size of the array
    label.new(bar_index, close, str.tostring(array.size(result)))
SMACalcul = ta.sma(array.get(result, array.size(result)-1), 50)
plot(SMACalcul)
```